# Drupal: png is not allowed extension (but it is!)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm running Drupal on IIS server 6.

I'm having an interesting error to upload images into my node. I get "png" is not a known file.

See image:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/pngError.png

But I've added png (default settings) to the allow image files list, and indeed you can see in the same image, that png is an allowed extension.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe Drupal does a content check and can't recognize the format? Have you tried it with different png files?

Comment: ok, i've tried several files and jpg extension as well, same error. It just doesn't accept images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a known bug in Drupal core on IIS. Your specific error message is found [here](http://drupal.org/node/419734), which points to the Drupal core bug [here](http://drupal.org/node/307636). The bug is still open, but it sounds like there's a working solution and I just uploaded a patch there to make the fix a little easier to apply.

Comment: however, I can only see the thumbnail when the file is uploaded (and also if come back to see the same project back-end. But the image for the website is not saved at all. Is maybe something to fix in imagecache as well ? (actually the thumbnail is created... so it should work)

Comment: oh no, the thumbnail is not generated by imagecache.. i guess the problem is in imagecache there then. Any tip ? (the temp folder works)

Comment: yeah imagecache doesn't store any image (even the preview describing the imagecache preset is not created. I dunno if it is a permissions problem, but it is IIS Server, so I cannot change them.

Comment: There was a second bug, because I'm not using clean_urls. This is the solution: http://drupal.org/node/410200